# a-frame, .dae model looks weird if second one is added

Tags: aframe, collada

I have a assignment for school and I am trying to add several Collada models. But if I add the second one my first model starts to look all weird. Why does it does that and how do i fix.

Link to project: [bruggemanj.roccloud.nl/ROCVR](http://bruggemanj.roccloud.nl/ROCVR)

Comment: the provided link isnt working, and basically You did not give us any information about how You load Your models, or what exactly is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your A-Frame version, that has been fixed since. The example is currently on 0.2.0-rc1 (over a year ago), try upgrading to 0.5.0 (soon 0.6.0).

`<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>`